# Flying sideways, how is it done?

Tags: aerodynamics, aerobatics

I assume that the fuselage and tail fin can generate lift when flying sideways with a constant heading and a little pitch up (er, yaw right assuming left wing down) will introduce a vertical component to the thrust.

Is that all there is?  What else might be going on?

Comment: @fooot  Thanks.  it is a duplicate, I'll close.  Cheers.